# Puppeteer Page.$$eval() method returning empty arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm building a web scraping application with puppeteer. I'm trying to get an array of links to scrape from but it returns an empty array.

```
const scraperObject = {
    url: 'https://www.walgreens.com/',
    async scraper(browser){
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
        await page.goto(this.url);
        // Wait for the required DOM to be rendered
        await page.waitForSelector('.CA__Featured-categories__full-width');
        // Get the link to all the required links in the featured categories
        let urls = await page.$$eval('.list__contain >  ul#at-hp-rp-featured-ul > li', links => {
            // Extract the links from the data
            links = links.map(el => el.querySelector('li > a').href)
            return links;
        });
```

Whenever I ran this, the console would give me the needed array of links (example below).

```
Navigating to https://www.walgreens.com/...
[
'https://www.walgreens.com/seasonal/holiday-gift-shop?ban=dl_dl_FeatCategory_HolidayShop_TEST'
'https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/cough-cold-and-flu/ID=20002873-tier1?ban=dl_dl_FeatCategory_CoughColdFlu_TEST'
'https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/contact-lenses/ID=359432-tier2clense?ban=dl_dl_FeatCategory_ContactLenses_TEST'
]
```

So, from here I had the navigate to one of those urls through the code block below and rerun the same code to go through an array of categories to eventually navigate to the product listings page.

```
//Navigate to Household Essentials
        let hEssentials = await browser.newPage();
        await hEssentials.goto(urls[11]);
        // Wait for the required DOM to be rendered
        await page.waitForSelector('.content');
        // Get the link to all the required links in the featured categories
        let shopByNeedUrls = await page.$$eval('div.wag-row > div.wag-col-3 wag-col-md-6 wag-col-sm-6 CA__MT30', links1 => {
            // Extract the links from the data
            links1 = links1.map(el => el.querySelector('div > a').href)
            return links1;
        });


console.log(shopByNeedUrls);
    }
```

However, whenever I run this code through the console, I receive the same navigating message but then I return an empty array(as shown in the example below)

```
Navigating to https://www.walgreens.com/...
[]
```

If anyone is able to explain why I'm outputting an empty array, that'd be great. Thank you.

I've attempted to change the parameter of the page.waitForSelector method and the page.$$eval method. However none of them appeared to work and output the same result. In fact, I recieve a timeout error sometimes for the the page.waitForSelector method.

Comment: I don't think example.com is really your URL(s), making this not a [mcve]? It seems odd to me that you're using `waitForSelector` on something other than the selector used in your `$$`. Usually, you wait for the thing you're about to select rather than something else, unless there's some relationship between the two different selectors.

Comment: If you're timing out on a `waitForSelector` you expect to succeed (usually because you validated it in dev tools), oftentimes it's because your script is being blocked, or the element is in a shadow root or iframe that devtools has automatically opened for you.

Comment: Hey there, I put example.com as a placeholder. I edited the link to further reflect the actual issue as well as the arrays.

Comment: My intended purpose for the selector were to have the scraper navigate to the category I want from the starting URL. I listed the links of categories in an array and had the scraper navigate to that link. I then intended to do it again to navigate to another page until it eventually reached the product-listing page. I hope that makes sense.